# Adding additional input elements to the google API autocomplete places form

Tags: google-maps

I am creating a form to receive information on an event.  I am using the google API autocomplete places in order to receive the user input for location of the event.  I also want to include information like: date, time, type of event and so on all on the same form.  I am having trouble posting the data for all the elements outside of the google API elements to my php file.  Am I allowed to do this or will I need to make two independent forms and get the location first and then all my other information.  I appreciate your help.